# How to takeWhile elements in a list wrapped in a monad

Tags: list, haskell, types, monads

Got a little puzzle I was wondering if you could help me clarify.

Let's define a function that returns a list:

```
let f = replicate 3
```

What we want to do is map this function to an infinite list, concatenate the results, and then take only things that match a predicate.

```
takeWhile (< 3) $ concatMap f [1..]
```

Great! That returns `[1,1,1,2,2,2]`, which is what I want.

Now, I want to do something similar, but the function f now wraps its results in a Monad.  In my usecase, this is the IO monad, but this works for discussing my problem:

```
let f' x = Just $ replicate 3 x
```

To map and concat, I can use:

```
fmap concat $ mapM f' [1..5]
```

That returns: `Just [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]`

If I want to use `takeWhile`, this still works:

```
fmap (takeWhile (< 3) . concat) $ mapM f' [1..5]
```

Which returns: Just [1,1,1,2,2,2].  Great!

But, if I make the list over which I map an infinite list this does not do what I expected:

```
fmap (takeWhile (< 3) . concat) $ mapM f' [1..]
```

Seems like the `takeWhile` is never happening. Somehow, I'm not getting the lazy computation I was expecting. I’m a bit lost.

Answer (score 8):

The problem isn't that `fmap` + `takeWhile` doesn't work with infinite lists wrapped in a monad. The problem is that `mapM` can't produce an infinite list (at least not in the Maybe monad).

Think about it: If `f'` returns `Nothing` for any item in the list, `mapM` has to return `Nothing`. However `mapM` can't know whether that will happen until it has called `f'` on all items in the list. So it needs to iterate through the whole list before it knows whether the result is `Nothing` or `Just`. Obviously that's a problem with infinite lists.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I can use instead?

Comment: More generally, mapM is not (and cannot be) lazy for any monad where (>>=) is strict in its first argument.  That includes Maybe, [], IO, and quite a few other things.

Comment: @Daniel: The only real option is to explicitly write the control flow you intend.  Yes, it's less convenient.  Such is the price of sacrificing laziness.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
takeWhileM :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m [a]
takeWhileM p [] = return []
takeWhileM p (m:ms) = do 
    x <- m
    if p x
      then liftM (x:) (takeWhileM p ms) 
      else return []
```

See sepp2k's answer for an explanation of why you are losing laziness.  The Identity monad or the *nonempty* list monad, for example, wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Note that iteratees provide a more general solution to this problem.

Comment: @John, interesting!  I didn't make that connection :-)

Comment: @John, I'd love to see a more gentle intro do iteratees. I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around them.

Comment: very interesting, thanks! you could make it resemble `sequence` definition more, I think, with `do { x<-m; guard (p x); xs<-takeWhileM p ms; return (x:xs)}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't mapM an infinite list of Maybes.  mapM is map followed by sequence.  Here is the definition of sequence:

```
sequence ms = foldr k (return []) ms
  where
    k m m' = do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x:xs) }
```

From this we see that sequence evaluates every monadic value in the list.  Since it's an infinite list, this operation will not terminate.

EDIT:

luqui and Carl make a good point that this doesn't generalize to any monad.  To see why it doesn't work for Maybe we need to look at the implementation of (>>=):

```
(>>=) m k = case m of
    Just x  -> k x
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

The important point here is that we do a case on m.  This makes the m strict because we have to evaluate it to figure out how to continue execution.  Note that we're not casing on x here, so it remains lazy.

Comment: "Evaluating" infinitely many monadic values is not really where the trouble is.  For example, you can easily do this in the `Identity` monad.